# pass artifacts between Concourse jobs without S3 or similar external resource

Tags: concourse

I am using concourse and build binaries that I would like to send off to integration tests. However they are lightweight and using an S3 bucket for permanent storage seems like overkill. Additionally I am versioning with `semver-resource`, which also seems to require S3 or such to back it.

Is there a way to configure a local on-worker or similar blobstore? can I use the Concourse postgres db to store my semver? it's small enough it should fit in a DB table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Concourse is designed so that the Concourse deployment itself is stateless, explicitly not providing artifact persistence and striving to be largely free of configuration.

This forces pipelines to be self-contained, which makes your CI reproducible. If your Concourse server burns down, you haven't lost anything special. You can just spin up another one and send up the original pipeline. Everything will then continue from where it left off: your versions will continue counting from where they were, rather than restarting from 0.0.0, and all of your artifacts are still wherever they are.

All that being said, you're free to deploy your own S3-compatible blob store. The `s3` resource should talk to it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

We use the semver resource with gist. Just get the clone id from the gist page:
[image]

then set your resource:

`- name: version
  type: semver
  source:
    driver: git
    branch: master
    uri: {{version-url}}
    file: Version
    private_key: {{github-private-key}}`